# Securely Transfer User Entered Password

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security

> I am new to ASP .Net MVC. I just wondered, how do I encrypt user entered password when he/she logs in into my site? The scenario is as follows:

- A registered user visits my side and clicks Log In
- Enteres his registered User Name and Password and clicks Log In
- Browser sends the above two plain strings (code wise), to the server.

> Here, how do I send the password securely to the server? I am not able to understand how it works in ASP .Net MVC generated HTML files. Can you please help me to understand this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't have much to do with ASP.NET MVC or any of the files it generates.  From the browser to the server-side code, a password is just text.  Though you should at least use an `input type="password"` in the HTML (or any server-side code which emits one) so that the browser knows to treat the value as a password, and ideally the channel between the browser and the server should be encrypted with SSL.

Once the password arrives at the server, you want to hash it.  Do this as soon as possible so that you're not holding on to a raw password string, which could accidentally get logged somewhere if an error occurs.  For properly hashing the password, there's a lot of reading which can be done on the subject.  I find [this page](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) explains the options and necessity of the whole thing quite well.  The main point is that you don't ever want to know a user's password, and you want it to be one-way hashed to it can't be retrieved.

(An important thing to remember here is that even though you run the server, you personally do not want to know a password.  A big reason for this is because users have a tendency to re-use passwords on other sites.  Someone may be inadvertently trusting you with their online banking password, for example.  It's not a question of how secure your server is or any data you expose on your own, but rather a question of handling *other people's* data responsibly.)

In general, how you handle the hashed password is pretty standard.  You can store it in your data and any time the user logs in you would hash their provided password and compare it with the stored hash.  This way you don't ever need to know the user's actual password, since comparing the hashes is enough to determine if the entered password was the same.